# Rails 3 has_many :through accessing attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, has-many-through

I am working with a has_many through for the first time, and despite a lot of reading here and in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association)  I am not understanding the correct way to access attributes on the through table. My tables are the same as this example from another post.

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :collaborators
       has_many :users, :through => :collaborators
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_many :collaborators
       has_many :products, :through => :collaborators
   end

   class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :product
      belongs_to :user
   end
```

Assuming that the collaborators table has additional attributes, say hours_spent, what is the correct way to find the hours_spent from the collaborator table for a particular user and product?

When I have found my users via the product, and am iterating over them as in

```
    @product.users.each do |user|
```

This seems to work

```
    user.collaborator[0].hours_spent
```

I get the correct value, but since there should only be one  collaborator record for each User/Product pair, the index is throwing me off, making me think I’m doing something wrong.

Thank you for reading!

EDIT

Perhaps I am not getting the has_many through concept. Maybe a MySQL example would help.

What I was thinking is that if I did

```
    SELECT * FROM collaborators where user_id = 1;
```

I would expect a set (zero or more) as the result. Similarly

```
    SELECT * FROM collaborators where product_id = 1;
```

would also give me a set, but

```
    SELECT * FROM collaborators where user_id = 1 and product_id = 1;
```

would give at most 1 row.

If I am understanding properly, all 3 queries return a set. So I guess I need some kind of uniqueness constraint, but that would have to be a compound key of sorts, on both of the belongs to keys. Is that even possible? Is there a structure that better models this?

Thanks so much for the quick and helpful responses!

Comment: See `has_one` instead of `has_many`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After implementing this, what I found was that I think I had the correct relationships setup, I had to use the has_many :though as users could have many products, and it needed to be :through because there are additional attributes on the collaborator table. The sticking point was how to get there to only be a single Collaborator record for each user/product pair, and then how do I guarantee I got it. And to this point the answer I've found is it has to be done in code.

To make sure there is only a single record for each pair, I used

```
class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :product_id, :presence => true,  :uniqueness => {:scope => [:user_id], :message => "This is a duplicate join"}
```

And then to make doubly sure I'm finding the right record, I have a scope

```
 scope :collaboration_instance, lambda {|p_id, u_id| where("collaborations.product_id = ? && collaborations.user_id = ?", p_id, u_id)}
```

If someone has a more elegant solution, or just wants to improve this one, please post and I will change yours to the selected answer.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a single database row per pair, but when considering a single user, that user can be associated to many products, so a user can have many rows in the collaborators table. Similarly, when considering a single product, that product can be associated to many users, so a product can have many rows in the collaborators table.

Also, instead of using `user.collaborators[0].hours_spent`, use `user.collaborators.first.try(:hours_spent)` (which may return null), if you only want the first collaborator's hours spent.

If a single user can only have one single product and a single product can only have a single user, then switch the has_many's to has_one's for everything.

*Update: The preceding is the answer to the original question which has since been clarified via comments. See comments for detail and see comments on other answer by Peter.*

Comment: Users can have many products, and products can have many users. But there should be only one collaboration between a specific user and a specific product.

Comment: If I understand this properly, user.collaborators.first.try(:hours_spent) would give me the first collaboration for that user. Is there some rails magic that makes it the the first collaboration for that user for a specific product?

Comment: Ok, if a single user can only have one product, then on user, both the has_many ... and has_many ... :through should be has_one ... and has_one ... :through which is what @meagar and I were telling you. Then hours spent would be `user.collaborator.try(:hours_spent)`. Same with product if a single product can only be associated with a single user, but I doubt that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use **has_and_belongs_to_many**. If your Collaborator is used only to make link between User and Product without having more fields.

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    end

    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
       has_and_belongs_to_many :products
   end
```

The beetween migration would be:

```
class CreateUsersProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table "users_products", :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :product_id
    end
  end
end
```